# What is a right way to update a boolean field using link_to. Getting undefined method `model_name' for TrueClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the below `link_to` in a loop in my rails app

```
<%= link_to 'Up', Product.find(n.id).update_attribute(:opinion, true)%>
```

But I am unable to update it. Because it gives me the error

```
undefined method `model_name' for TrueClass:Class
```

So, I am wondering in this case what is the right way to update a boolean field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You are not updating the opinion after click the link, you are updating it when the page render.

Lets say your page has only the following code:

```
<%= link_to 'Up', Product.find(n.id).update_attribute(:opinion, true)%>
```

What actually happens when you hit that page is that the code wrapped on `<%= %>` is executed and used to generate an string, that will become your HTML. So while simplifying your expression, in one step of the execution you will have the following code:

```
<%= link_to 'Up', true %>
```

And this will generate the HTML

```
<a href="true">Up</a>
```

Which is not what you intend of.

### Solution

Create an action on your product controller that receives the product id, updates the product and redirects back. So, something like this:

On your route.rb

```
 resource :products do
   member do
     post 'update_opinion'
   end
 end
```

On your products_controller.rb:

```
 def update_opinion
   Product.find(params[:id]).update_attribute(:opinion, true)
   redirect_to :back
 end
```

On your view:

```
<%= link_to 'up', update_opinion_project_path(n) %>
```

Comment: I was trying that but the problem i am running into is when i have a code like this in the controller `@product = Product.find(params[:id])` . I am currently on the `product#index` view and there is no product id present as params. What other way can i find the entry? I hope i am making sense.

Comment: @psharma: you may really want to read some [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), please consider doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does something very different from what you seem to be pursuing.

The helper method [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) accepts two parameters: the link text and the link target, which can be:

- a string, like: `'http://stackoverflow.com'`;
- a hash referring all the single components of an internal URL, as defined by [routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html);
- an object, or an array of objects.

As second parameter, you are passing an expression:

```
Product.find(n.id).update_attribute(:opinion, true)
```

which is evaluated the first time the code runs, that is, during rendering.
The expression tries to update the attribute immediately and then returns a boolean that says if the operation succeeded or not: true if it successfully updated the attribute, false otherwise.

In your case, it appears to be successfully: it returns `true`.

Now, `true` is neighther a string nor an hash, so it is treated as an object, whose class is `TrueClass`. So it treats it as a model, but not being a model, it does not define the models methods; thus the error.

What you want to do is to put the code in a [controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html), and put the URL relative to the right controller action as second parameter of `link_to`.